# How do I code a histogram, pice chart, etc?

Tags: php

Hint: this may be a thinly disguised request for a FOSS component which alraeady does the same.

But, if such a beast is not forthcoming, then how do I go about it?  Given a series of (x,y) data, what's the best way to display them in manamagentspeak? Just some pretty pictures ... charts/graphs/histograms/scatter graphs/pie charts ...

---

Edit: When I said FOSS I ought to have stressed that I need something which can be used in a commercial applciation ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try using Google Charts http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/

It's really easy to build graphs using it's API.

Comment: +1 thanks, but I would be afraid that they might one day pull the service.

Comment: Graphite looked best, but doesn't work out of the box. Known bug, apparently. So, Google Charts it is

Answer (score 4):

Use a library such as [jpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/) or [graphpite](http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/) or [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: +1 Thanks.  I forgot to say that it's for a commerical app, so ... jpgraph costs a one-off US $98 for a perpetual commercial license for a single server, or $788 for multiple servers ...
   
pchart is GPL, can't use it.    graphpite  is LGPL and is looking good.  I am currently searching SourceForge and will get back to you.  Thansk again

Comment: Graphite looked best, but doesn't work out of the box. Known bug, apparently. So, Google Charts it is